# PHP changing number to words

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, numbers, cpu-word

I have stored in my DB a row and in that row SubCategories

it has the following
2,56,81

What I need to do is change the numbers to the correct SubCategories
ie:
1 = Sports
2 = Camping
3 = Climing

etc

I thought I would be able to do the following

```
$parts = explode(',', $row['SubCategories']);
```

But now I ran into a slight issue with how do I turn that into the words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to create an array with the word definitions, and then use the numbers as keys:

```
$words = array (
    1 => 'Sports',
    2 => 'Camping',
    3 => 'Climbing'
);

$parts = explode(',', '1,3');

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++ )
{
    $parts[$i] = $words[ $parts[$i] ];
}
```

See it in action: http://codepad.org/vs2dJi5E

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do a query for those category names, using a `WHERE IN()` ([Details here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)).

However, it would be better to just have a parent column in the row for the subcategory, and query `WHERE parent = 2` to get subcategories for that category